# Murdered by the wise, who am I?

Tags: riddle

This is the first real riddle I have created, so I hope it is not too easy!

> Murdered by the wise
>   Who destroyed all of my lives
>   When I’m at your door, you better pray,
>   Pray the darkness all away,
>   I would most gladly munch on a feather
>   Only if I was not attached to a mortal’s tether

Who am I?

**EDIT**

I took out some of the lines in the riddle to make it harder. I have made them into a hints instead.

**Hints**

**1**

> I hunt and hunt, and stalk and prey

**2**

> Sometimes i am turned a stray

**3**

> Black and white, not often grey

Comment: hunt and `prey` not `pray` ?

Comment: @Jasen Thanks for pointing that out. The question has been edited.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you a

> Cat?

Murdered by the wise

> Curiosity killed the cat (Thanks to: Darrel Hoffman)
>  First answer was: The wise meaning the humans (egyptians who mummified cats)

Who destroyed all of my lives

> Cats have 9 lives

I hunt and hunt, and stalk and pray,

> Cat hunt for food(birds for example).

Sometimes i am turned a stray,

> A stray/lost cat

Black and white, not often grey

> Black and white cats, you don't often see a fully grey cat.

When I’m at your door, you better pray,
&
Pray the darkness all away,

> The superstition of black cats as an evil omen. "Pray the darkness all away" might mean to pray that the black cat leaves you alone. (Thanks to: Bulldogg6404)
>  I first had:  Catwoman!

It would most gladly munch on a feather

> Eating birds

Only if it was not attached to a mortal’s tether

> Leashes (Thanks to Oreo's for the update).
>  I first wrote: Cats are often hidden inside a house as like a dog is stuck with it's chain.

Comment: Close, but you have not explained all of the lines :) Keep trying

Comment: @Oreo filled em in, but I'm unsure about the Pray the darkness all away one.

Comment: @Decypher chances are he is referring to the superstition of black cats as an evil omen. "Pray the darkness all away" might mean to pray that the black cat leaves you alone.

Comment: @Bulldogg6404 Yep you are right on that one, keep in mind that the previous line is also describing this.

Comment: Also "a mortal's tether" was intended to refer to leashes that we put on pets

Comment: I'd say "Murdered by the wise" is a reference to the adage that "Curiosity killed the cat".

Comment: The Egyptians revered cats and would not have killed them. Also, "a mortal's tether" could refer to the domestication of cats so they hang around even if you let them roam outside.

Comment: @KellyS.French they mummified cats even when they were alive also.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman thanks I edited my answer to it.

Comment: @Decypher I know they mummified cats but usually it was so they could be [entombed with their owner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cats_in_ancient_Egypt) but the references aren't too clear on whether they would mummify a living cat so it could be sealed in with the owner. In any case, I don't think the Egyptians are the 'wise' in this case, I'm with DarrelHoffman.

Comment: plenty of gray cats - that's the clue I'm not sure of. I was thinking of some kind of wild cat, like a snow leopard which is *black and white, not often grey*, but even that doesn't fit perfectly and then some other clues don't make as much sense.

Comment: @Oreo is this answer now correct/ able to be 'accepted' as the correct answer?